# Invalid arguments error trapping on implode()

Tags: php, error-handling

In the script below, I'm getting an invalid arguments error on the "echo implode()" line:

> Warning: implode() [function.implode]:
>   Invalid arguments passed in...

Here is the script:

```
if ( !function_exists('wp_tag_cloud') || get_option('cb2_noposttags')) return;
$unlinkTags = get_option('cb2_unlinkTags'); 
echo '<div class="links"><h2>Tags</h2>';
if($unlinkTags)
{
        $tags = get_tags();
        foreach ($tags as $tag){
            $ret[]= $tag->name;
        }
        echo implode(', ', $ret);
}
else
{
    wp_tag_cloud('separator=, &smallest=11&largest=11');
}
echo '</div>';
```

How might I rework this to catch the invalid argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialise $ret as an array **before** your foreach loop.

```
$ret = array();
$tags = get_tags();
foreach ($tags as $tag){
   $ret[]= $tag->name; 
} 
echo implode(', ', $ret);
```

Then, if get_tags() doesn't return anything, $ret is still being passed into implode as an array (but as an empty array) rather than as a null

Comment: Actually it must be initialized before `if($unlinkTags)`.

Comment: @Felix, nope, indentation is just messed up. Mark is correct.

Answer (score 3):

just add: `$ret = array();` before your loop

at the moment, $ret isn't defined if there is nothing added inside your for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

For a slightly different flavor, you could just test if it's an array or not:

```
if (is_array($ret)) echo implode(', ', $ret);
```